# How to validate multiple Typo3 action parameters in combination?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

The Typo3 documentation describes @Validate annotations which can be used to validate parameters for a single controller action:

- https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/book-extbasefluid/master/en-us/9-CrosscuttingConcerns/2-validating-domain-objects.html

However, it is only described how to add a custom validator for a single parameter. It is possible to add multiple validation annotations, but then again each of them can validate just a single parameter, not multiple parameters in combination.

**First question:** It is possible to add a validator which checks multiple parameters, or even all parameters, of a specific controller action?

Of course the obvious workaround is to combine multiple arguments in a single argument, using e.g. an array or an object. But this is especially annoying if the arguments themselves are already (independent) model objects.

**Second question:** If the answer to the first question is "it's impossible", what is the recommended way to combine the arguments of a controller action?

(e.g.: Should one use an array? That seems to be not preferred in Typo3 due to the lack of type safety and other features. Should one create a class? But which kind of class would that be? A Utility class? A Model class? But that model class would then need suppressed persistence? This seems to be all messy.)

I'm using **version 9.5 of Typo3**, but if things are different in version 10, that would be interesting as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge I suggest using a data transfer object (DTO) for this purpose.
If your models have to be validated in combination, but do not belong to any other entity, combining them in a DTO is probably the best way to go. Consequently the validation logic is then clustered in a single validator.

See also this blog post about DTOs: https://usetypo3.com/dtos-in-extbase.html

Comment: Thanks for your response! This article is great, it just misses one detail: Is there an agreed directory and naming style for DTOs, such as `Classes/DTO/Foo.php` or `Classes/Domain/DTO/FooDTO.php`?

Comment: Not that I know. The news extension does it like this: https://github.com/georgringer/news/tree/master/Classes/Domain/Model/Dto